# Performance of MySQL UNION LIMITs

Tags: mysql

I've got two distinct MySQL tables that both contain time-series data (in that both contain a 'timestamp' column).  With the exception of the 'timestamp' column, the two tables do not share any common features besides a 'client_id' column.

```
table_a
- id
- client_id
- timestamp
- ...

table_b
- id
- client_id
- timestamp
- ...
```

Both tables are indexed on (client_id, timestamp).

I'm trying to combine these two tables into a single paginated time-series.  To be concrete, by this I mean that I'm trying to load N records (with an offset of M) from the union of `table_a` and `table_b`, ordered by `timestamp`.

I've tried to do this with a statement like this:

```
(SELECT 'a', id FROM table_a WHERE client_id=1) UNION (SELECT 'b', id FROM table_b WHERE client_id=1) ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 100;
```

Unfortunately, the resulting query seems to be grabbing all matching rows from both tables, combining, and then applying the LIMIT.

Note that queries against the individual tables are super fast:

```
SELECT 'a', id FROM table_a WHERE client_id=1 ORDER by timestamp LIMIT 100
```

Is there a better way to index the tables or write the UNION query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't make good use of indexes here because there are two separate indexes in two separate tables.

You could add a limit to each individual select, but this will only work for the first page, and not for offsets.

If you are willing to drop the requirement that a "page" is limit plus offset, you can paginate some other absolute (rather than relative) way, such as by day. E.g.:

```sql
(SELECT 'a', id, timestamp FROM table_a WHERE client_id=1 AND timestamp BETWEEN '2014-04-18 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-18 23:59:59')
UNION
(SELECT 'b', id, timestamp FROM table_b WHERE client_id=1 AND timestamp BETWEEN '2014-04-18 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-18 23:59:59')
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

However, it is also possible that your data is not fully normalized and that the common attributes from table_a and table_b should be in a third table. This pattern is called "joined table inheritance".

For example:

```sql
table_common
- id
- type ('a' or 'b')
- client_id
- timestamp
- primary key: (id, type) if id is not unique.
- index: (client_id, timestamp)

table_a
- id (same value as in table_common)
...

table_b
- id (same value as in table_common)
...
```

Since you are now sharing a common index, you can do the following:

```sql
SELECT id, type, timestamp FROM table_common
WHERE client_id=1 ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 100;
```

If you need more fields from the child tables, use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and include `type` in the condition:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_common
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_a ON table_common.type='a' AND table_common.id=table_a.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b ON table_common.type='b' AND table_common.id=table_b.id
ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is to apply the same LIMIT to each of the individual queries, since by definition you will never need more than N rows from any of the individual queries:

```
(SELECT 'a', id FROM table_a WHERE client_id=1 ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 100) 
UNION 
(SELECT 'b', id FROM table_b WHERE client_id=1 ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 100) 
ORDER BY timestamp 
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: @FrancisAvila, good point. I didn't look closely enough at the question.